# ./autogen error while building linphone for windows

Tags: perl, mingw, linphone, autogen

I have downloaded the Linphone opensource and build using MinGW. I have followed the steps given by the README.mingw. When I use the command "./autogen.sh" to automake the belle-sip, I got the following error.I guess there might be some problems related perl module, and I search the solutions on the Internet. However, still cannot solve the problem.

```
Chi@Nimal_PC /c/source/belle-sip
$ ./autogen.sh
Generating build scripts in belle-sip...
+ libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: $pkgltdldir is not a directory: `/mingw/share/libtool'
+ aclocal -I /share/aclocal
Can't locate Automake/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/share/automake-1.11 /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/msys/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) at /c/MinGW/bin/aclocal-1.11 line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/MinGW/bin/aclocal-1.11 line 37.
+ autoheader
Can't locate Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/share/autoconf /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/msys/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) at /c/MinGW/bin/autoheader-2.68 line 42.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/MinGW/bin/autoheader-2.68 line 42.
+ automake --force-missing --add-missing --copy
Can't locate Automake/Struct.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/share/automake-1.11 /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/msys/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) at /c/MinGW/bin/automake-1.11 line 47.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/MinGW/bin/automake-1.11 line 47.
+ autoconf
/c/MinGW/bin/autoconf-2.68: line 501: /mingw/bin/autom4te-2.68: No such file or directory
/c/MinGW/bin/autoconf-2.68: line 501: exec: /mingw/bin/autom4te-2.68: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing automake dependency that you can install from MinGW Installation Manager. From that install automake.